# UIPanGestureRecognizer - ImageView snaps back at original position after pan

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am testing the following project using UIPanGestureRecognizer.
How can I "pin" an image after panning?

**This is what the code is intended to do:**

(1) 2 ImageViews(image1, image2) are on the ViewController. Positions are defined by constraints.

(2) There are 2 target ImageViews (target1, target2) on which I want to move the image1 and image2 to.

(3) When I move one of the images on either one of the target images, I want the image to stay there, unable to move again. Also, the second image cannot be placed on the filled target.

(4) When I move the second image, I can move it to the empty target, the image stay there unable to be moved again.

**The issue with this code:**

This code works up to step(3).
The problem is that when I start moving the second image, the first image I put on a target snaps back to the original position.

```
import UIKit

class sample: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var image2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var target1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var target2: UIImageView!

    var target1flg: Bool!
    var target2flg: Bool!

    var imageViewOrigin: CGPoint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        target1flg = true
        target2flg = true

        addPanGesture(v: image1)
        addPanGesture(v: image2)

    }

    func addPanGesture(v: UIView) {

        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sample.handlePan(sender:)))
        v.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    }

    @objc func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let pannedImageView = sender.view!

        switch sender.state {

        case .began:

            imageViewOrigin = pannedImageView.frame.origin
            view.bringSubview(toFront: pannedImageView)

        case .changed:

            moveViewWithPan(v: pannedImageView, sender: sender)

        case .ended:
            if pannedImageView.frame.intersects(target1.frame) && target1flg == true {
                snapView(v: pannedImageView, targetBox: target1)
                target1flg = false

            }
            else if pannedImageView.frame.intersects(target2.frame) && target2flg == true  {
                snapView(v: pannedImageView, targetBox: target2)
                target2flg = false

            }
            else {
                returnViewToOrigin(v: pannedImageView, loc: imageViewOrigin)
            }

        default:
            break
        }
    }


    func moveViewWithPan(v: UIView, sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)

        v.center = CGPoint(x: v.center.x + translation.x, y: v.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
    }


    func returnViewToOrigin(v: UIView, loc: CGPoint) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            v.frame.origin = loc
        })
    }

    func snapView(v:UIView, targetBox:UIImageView){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

            v.center = CGPoint(x:targetBox.center.x, y: targetBox.center.y)
            v.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

I changed image1 and image2 position setting by:
(1)deleting constraints for the images.
(2)adding them under a new View and position them by using size [inspector > View].